# 2 weeks old, sleeping, crying, eating

Tags: newborn

My baby is 2 weeks old (tomorrow) and I have a few questions:

1. He eats every 2 hours (not all the time, sometimes after 3, 3 and half hours),
   he eats 50ml, sometimes 60ml (most of the time it is a mother milk, but at the night he eats formula), is this ok ?
2. He cries a lot when he is naked :) and he wants to sleep but instead of that he cries, need to worry about this ?
3. Is it normal for baby to breath fast (not all the time, just after he eats and I put him in the bed)?
4. He sleeps much more better in transporter and on my chest then in his own bed, is something I need to change?

Thanks for your help and I appreciate your advice.

Comment: "Baby sleeps, cries and eats. Film at 11."

Comment: @DanielRoseman: You had the energy to watch a film?

Comment: I want to watch movie so bad, but as Dave mention my wife & I, we don't have enough energy, i wonder when we will be back to our old routine :)

Comment: @PetarAbramac this is a lot of questions in one! Would you want to break it up into two questions perhaps? One about the crying, one about sleeping.. and if you can give us a detail about his breathing, when he does this.. I would suggest getting him checked by a doctor for this, and in general, as he is very young and we can't diagnose if anything is wrong.. please keep your questions, just separate them and please tell us what your doctor says thanks +1 :)

Comment: @Skippy, sorry about that, next time i will post questions that are in relation with each other, sorry for that. His fast breathing is after eating time when i put him in the bad (on his left side), i think he's trying to catch his dream :) because when he sleeps on my chest he doesn't do that. When i got information from the doctor i will share it with all of you. Thanks

Comment: I constantly write bad :D instead of bed (strange kind of deformation, sorry:)

Comment: @PetarAbramac don't worry about it the community seems more than ok with it :)

Comment: Combined feeding (breast and formula) isn't a big deal if you need to do that (that would be good to follow up in another question.)  Your baby getting food is always better than your baby getting no food.  Breastfeeding doesn't have to be exclusive to still have benefits.  That said during some classes and support groups on breastfeeding they did advise that the best breastmilk is usually produced at night while mum is resting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that your baby just spent months in a cozy, warm, dark womb. Being out in the light and the cool, dry air is unfamiliar. And crying is the only way to express discomfort  - babies cry for hunger, for tiredness, for being too cold or too hot, for wanting to be held...

When you hold him, try to snuggle him up like he was in the womb. He is not used to having his feet free or not having his head push against something. When you put him down to sleep, try swaddling him - wrapping a blanket around him an a way that keeps his legs and arms from moving too much, like being in the womb. Babies who spend too much in a transporter can develop a flat spot on the backs of their heads, so between sleeps, make sure you take him out.

Infants can breathe between 30 and 60 times a minute - it's pretty quick, and nothing to worry about.

As Dave says, it all sounds very normal!

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you have a normal newborn just like the rest of us did at some point (or some of us are hoping to have). They all have preferences, and may be uncomfortable in some positions and not in others. Our job is to feed them, change them, and make sure that they are as comfortable as possible. Their job is to challenge us by sending mixed messages and robbing us from sleep.

Seriously, nothing sounds out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 6):

To answer question number 4. "He sleeps much more better on my chest" is natural, and it's good to him. Please refer "Kangaroo care (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangaroo_care)".

Answer (score 2):

My little guy (baby #2) is about 6 weeks old. What you have listed are qualities of a normal newborn. Babies like to be warm...so not naked. They are also used to the womb. This means warm, noisy, and cramped. When your baby lays on your chest, he can hear your heartbeat, a sound he was used to hearing in the womb. Swaddling works for some babies (my son decided after a couple weeks that he will scream if we swaddle his arms, bit still loves his legs tucked up and swaddled). We also use a womb bear. It is a stuffed bear that makes the wooshing sound of the womb. This provides some white noise for him. Babies also go through breathing stages. Sometimes it will be fast and shallow, sometimes deep and slow, and sometimes they'll have a brief pause. All normal. We learned this with our first one when he was in the nicu hooked up to all those monitors. We asked the nurse about the breathing patterns and she told us that it was normal. As to how much he is eating, it sounds about right. That is right around 2 oz and that is normal for a baby 2 weeks old.